# Auto-select in Materialize Multi-Select drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, materialize, multi-select

I have a multi-select field in materialize:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="somevalue" class="{{#if $eq isActive}}active{{/if}}">Some Value</option>
</select>
```

and want to auto select any values returned from the database when the user goes into edit mode.

In looking at the section in chrome dev tools I see it creates an `li` with a checkbox and the li has `class="active"` when it's checked.

I've tried setting that class programmatically in javascript, but still the selections aren't checked.

Is there something special I need to do to get those options to check "automatically" for edit modes?

I'm using Meteor and Blaze to create this layout, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The below approach should work,

```
<select multiple>
    {{#if $eq isActive}}
        <option value="somevalue" selected="selected">Some Value</option>
    {{else}}
        <option value="somevalue">Some Value</option>
    {{/if}}
</select>
```

Also, make sure that the helper that determines whether the item is active or not to return the correct value.